# When my app attempts to OCR an img tag, Tesseract.js fails with an obtuse error

Tags: javascript, tesseract, tesseract.js

The error is

```
/somepath/node_modules/tesseract.js/src/common/desaturate.js:22
    } else { throw 'Invalid ImageData' }
             ^
Invalid ImageData
```

The img tag has its visibility set to hidden, the src is dynamic (but populated via javascript) to a file:// url (electron app). In the window's javascript, I'm loading it with this:

```
var Tesseract = require('tesseract.js');
```

And I have a Tesseract object available if I check in Dev Tools. Since it's easier to tinker in Dev Tools, I've been using that primarily, and I run a statement something like the following:

```
Tesseract.recognize(ocrPage, 'eng').then(function(result){console.log(result)}).progress(message => console.log(message)).then(result => console.log(result));
```

From this, I'll get 10 or 12 lines of console.log, ending with this:

```
{status: "initializing api", progress: 0.6}
```

Immediately after which I get the error at the top of the post in the terminal window's console log.

I've ruled out any problems with the image itself. I've used over a dozen test images, including the example from http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/.

Does this image tag need explicit width/height or something of that nature? Is this a cross-origins issue of some sort? Does npm install screw up the library? Having very little luck debugging it and not even sure where to start.

Comment: @Rup That's in the tesseract code. It's just "if(image.data){", and image is passed in as the only argument to the function. The file itself is small, on 25 lines or so. Something to do with converting the image object to grayscale. But I get this error even when I start with grayscale/monochrome test images.

Comment: It looks like image.data is intended to be the image as a bitmap, decoded from PNG/JPEG etc., based on the node code. There's equivalent code in the browser version too. I'd try debugging loadImage() to see how it's trying to read it and presumably failing.

Comment: This has something to do with attempting to ocr the image from the renderer process. Nearly identical code works as expected from the main process. I'm going to attempt to rework this so I can do that, but I'm still interested in knowing how to make it work in the renderer if anyone knows the answer.